# beaglebone black power supply for hexapod

Tags: power, otherservos, beagle-bone, hexapod

I am trying to build a *hexapod* with camera interfacing using a **beaglebone black** for college project. I'm not sure what **power supply** to give so it can power up to *bot,* having in mind that it should be **portable (mobile)** and it should power about *18 servo motors* along with the *camera*, *wifi* and the *processor*. Your help is needed very badly as i'm nearing the *deadline* for the project.

Comment: What type of servos are you using (a link would be helpful)? Also, by mobile I assume you mean battery powered and not a small wall adapter (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18 servos is a lot of power no matter their size but you are going to need to be more specific with what kind of servos you are talking about. That said, this [What is the best way to power a large number (27) servos at 5 V?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/416/what-is-the-best-way-to-power-a-large-number-27-servos-at-5-v?rq=1) is a good answer to your question.